# Help with the integral of e

Tags: integration, exponential-function

It has been years since calc 2 but if I remember correctly the $\int$ calculates the area under a curve.  I have some code that is approximating the area under a given function by calculating the values at an interval then averaging those values and multiplying by the x. I'm trying to improve the performance and accuracy.

The basic function is:

$1-e^{\frac{x}{1000}}$

Graphing this produces a curve that is bounded at y at 1. So the area under this function should be $<$ $x$

Ok to the math and hopefully someone sees the basic mistake I must be making
(basically calculating the area between $|_0^{100}$

$\int_0^{100} (1-e^{\frac{-x}{1000}})  $

$\int_0^{100} 1 - \int_0^{100}e^{\frac{-x}{1000}}$

$x |_0^{100} - \int_0^{100}e^{\frac{-1}{1000}*x}$

$100 - \frac{-1000}{1} e^{\frac{-x}{1000}}|_0^{100} $

$100 + 1000 *e^{\frac{-x}{1000}} |_0^{100}$

$100 + 1000 * (e^{\frac{-100}{1000}} - e^0)$

$100 + 1000 * (e^{\frac{-1}{10}} - 1) $

$100 + 1000 * (.9048 -1) $ (1.01 - 1) (Fixed)

$100 + 1000 * -.09516 $

$100 +  -95.16$

$4.8374$

And this seems very wrong! (FIXED!)

I believe the answer should be about $\approx 4.829$

Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: You mean $\int_{0}^{100}1=1|_0^{100}$?

Comment: @juniven But somehow he fixed the error with another one in the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three errors in this:

---

$\text{Error 1:}$

$$\int1\ dx=x+c\ne1+c$$

So we should have

$$\int_0^{100}1\ dx=\left.x\vphantom{\cfrac11}\right|_0^{100}=100$$

but somehow this hasn't actually affected the answer, since you end up with $100$ anyways.

---

$\text{Error 2:}$

$$\int_0^{100}e^{-x/1000}dx\ne-1000\int_0^{100}e^{-x/1000}dx$$

This appears around the spot where you try to evaluate the integral.  However, again, you come to the correct end result, leaving us with error 3...

---

$\text{Error 3:}$

$$e^{-1/10}=0.904837419\ne1.105171$$

It appears you forgot to make the negative sign in the exponent come into play.  Once you put this in, everything should be fine.

Comment: error 1 & 2 are my fault as I didn't type it as I meant it,

Comment: 3 was the real error!

Comment: @CarlBartlett Yes, I kind of figured.  Which leaves error 3, the simplest of errors.  You know, when I took my Calculus I exam, I aced my non-calculator parts.  But then again, I'm not so good with calculators... so yeah, that happened.